# HttpWebResponse is always null

Tags: c#, http, exception, post

I have method which makes `HTTP POST`

I call this method with try catch like this

```
try
{
   returnString = MakePost(gatewayEnpoint, data);
   return returnString;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
   if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
   {
       return ex.Message.ToString();
   }
}
```

but `response` is always null.

How i can handle HTTP exceptions? i need status codes

thanks

Comment: what is the exception you get? E.g. if you can't conncet to the remote there will be no response.

Comment: Share details of exception, what statusCode you get... also share MakePost method... further if server side is in your control does the client hit reached there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There won't be a response if the client hasn't even managed to contact the server.

The cases in which there *will* be a response are for things like 404 status codes.

If you're *never* getting a response, then you're probably making some other mistake (e.g. trying to contact a server which doesn't exist).

I would *strongly* recommend that you don't return success and error cases in the same way as you're doing now, by the way.

Comment: In my customer network i am facing the same issue. HTTP error response is null. Wireshark confirmed me that i am getting 500 internal server error, but still response is null. With the same customer server with my client(different network) i am getting valid error response. Any idea on customer client(windows 7) anything(firewall/.Net library installed) is blocking http error response and setting to null? Please help.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Are you talking specifically about the response within a `WebException`? I've no idea what would be causing that.

Comment: Yes Jon. I am getting response as null within WebException.